# Unable to connect to beacon service

Tags: android, ibeacon, android-ibeacon

I'm trying to use "android-beacon-library for detecting beacons" in Android. But I keep getting "Cannot contact service to set scan periods" in the log and beacons are not getting scanned. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show code snippets of what you are trying to do, please

Comment: Which type of connection you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This log message indicates that the app is getting a `RemoteException` talking to the `BeaconService`, probably indicating that the `BeaconService` was not started properly.  The library will attempt to contact the service to adjust the scan periods as your app enters the foreground (an Activity is visible) or the background (no Activity is visible.)  You probably get this log message once for each time your app enters the foreground or background when the `BeaconService` is not started.

Why is your app's `BeaconService` not started?  There are lots of things that could cause this, but the most likely thing is an issue with the project setup.

1. If you are setting up your app for background detection, make sure you have a custom `Application` class set up as described in the "Starting an App in the Background" section here: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html.
2. If you are explicitly binding to the service with the `BeaconManager` class, verify you actually get a callback to `onBeaconServiceConnect()` per the "Monitoring Example Code" here: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html.
3. If you are using Eclipse, perhaps manifest merging is not enabled.  Edit your `project.properties` file and make sure it has the line: `manifestmerger.enabled=true`  Full instructions on configuring Eclipse are here: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/configure.html

If none of these things solve your issue, then you really need to post your code that sets up beacon detection with the library so we can assist further.

Comment: @AimanB please open a new question so not to hijack the one here.